# Вопрос по использованию Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, битрикс

Приветствую! У меня нарисовался следующий вопрос.

Я делаю сайт на Битрикс, воспользовался компонентом news.list, подогнал его под себя, все нормально. Он представляет собой список блоков, при нажатии на которые разворачивается дополнительный блок с информацией. С этим все хорошо. Я хочу, чтобы выводилось на странице только 6 штук, а остальные на других страницах, а так как сайт одностраничный я решил воспользоваться Ajax для навигации. В настройках компонента выставил галочки "Включить режим AJAX" и "Включить прокрутку к началу компонента".

В итоге, когда заходишь первый раз или обновляешь страницу блоки разворачиваются по клику как надо, но, если воспользоваться навигацией, то они прекращают реагировать на клик (такое чувство, что Ajax полностью перехватывает событие on click). 
Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы блоки продолжали правильно реагировать на клик после того, как сработал Ajax запрос и реально ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax не перехватывает событие onclick, он его **не добавляет** к загруженному html'у. 
Это вполне логично, поскольку js добавляет *обработчики* к элементам при **загрузке** страницы браузером, а ajax загружает дополнительный контент уже **после** этого. 
Что Вас спасет? 
1) Делегирование событий. Например методом jquery **on**:

```
$('идентификатор (селектор) блока, который загружается ajax'ом')
.on('click (event, событие, которое должно срабатывать)', 
'selector элемента, которому нужно это назначить, например ссылка - a),
function(){});
```

2) Велосипедирование с добавлением js-кода при загрузке html-страницы ajax'ом. Но это не очень удобно, т.к. вызывает боль и зуд в заднице.